# Add foreign property to LINQ-to-SQL model

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq-to-sql

How can I add a custom property to my LINQ-to-SQL model that automatically joins a value from a foreign table, effectively de-normalizing an association?

My (simplified) database model:

```
Customer              Group
------------          ----------
CustID [PK]           GroupID [PK]
FirstName             GroupName
LastName              ...
GroupID [FK]
...
```

My first (simplified) approach:

```
public partial class Customer
{
    public string GroupName
    {
        get { return this.Group.GroupName; }
    }
}
```

In reality, `GroupName` is a few associated tables away, requiring me to join, filter, group, select, etc. to get to it. All doable with plain SQL.

Accessing `GroupName` triggers a separate SQL query. I know I could preload the Group model with `loadOptions.LoadWith<Customer>(c => c.Group)`, but I would need to remember that and do it for every new DataContext, and I don't really need the Group model (and all models inbetween) at all. I just want to have the GroupName as readonly string on the Customer.

So I basically want to extend the model like I would do with a SQL query:

```
SELECT Customer.*, Group.GroupName
FROM Customer
INNER JOIN Group
ON Customer.GroupID = Group.GroupID
```

Can this be done with a LINQ-to-SQL model? Alternatives?

Comment: Why not make a View or Stored Procedure that does the logic for you so you can just get the values without having to worry about any of that on the C# side?  Am I misunderstanding what you're trying to do?

Comment: @EMUEVIL: Using a View instead would have been my next approach. It just adds additional problems with updates, inserts and deletions, and also I'd like to avoid modifying the database since it doesn't belog to my application (SAP integration).

Comment: Understandable!  I'm just not sure what type of object you could get back from your LINQ query if you aren't returning a row of one of the predefined tables.  Perhaps you could make a custom table object (or dataview?) that has that extra column, get your predefined result table from the query, then add a column and fill the values in with a LINQ lookup?  I'm no C# expert though so hopefully you can get a more informed opinion from someone as well.